# HTML5 Canvas - Can I handle a video with Easeljs into a canvas tag?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-video, easeljs

I would like put a video into a canvas tag and handle from there, eg. color, control playback with scroll etc...

But I didn't undertand how it's possible (and if) by Easel lib.

JAVASCRIPT

```
function init(){//init() is in Body -> onload
  stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
  var ctx = stage.canvas.getContext('2d');
  var video = document.getElementById("video");

   createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", function(event){
       if(video.paused || video.ended) return false;
       drawFrame(video, stage, ctx);

  }
}//init

function drawFrame(v,s,c){
   bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(video);
   bitmap.draw(c);
   s.update();
}
```

This is the code, doesn't draw anything and after 5 or 6 sec goes to crash.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share the code and if possible a fiddle

Comment: Not easeljs, but may help: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/